# nsis - remove pinned icon from taskbar on uninstall

Tags: nsis, uninstallation, taskbar

I'm working on an app for a company and they requested that if the app is pinned to the taskbar, when uninstalling the app should be unpinned. If I just delete the icon from quicklaunch\user pinned\taskbar then it leaves a blank icon on the taskbar.

I need to somehow actually unpin it. The only thing I've come across is installing winshell plugin (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WinShell_plug-in) and then calling IStartMenuPinnedList::RemoveFromList (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774817(v=vs.85).aspx)

I'd rather not install a plugin if I don't need to. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSIS does not have native support for this interface so you have to use a plug-in. If you want to avoid that 3rd-party plug-in (written by me) then you can use the System plug-in instead:

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "Win\COM.nsh" ; NSIS v3+

!macro UnpinShortcut lnkpath
Push $0
Push $1
!insertmacro ComHlpr_CreateInProcInstance ${CLSID_StartMenuPin} ${IID_IStartMenuPinnedList} r0 ""
${If} $0 P<> 0
    System::Call 'SHELL32::SHCreateItemFromParsingName(ws, p0, g "${IID_IShellItem}", *p0r1)' "${lnkpath}"
    ${If} $1 P<> 0
        ${IStartMenuPinnedList::RemoveFromList} $0 '(r1)'
        ${IUnknown::Release} $1 ""
    ${EndIf}
    ${IUnknown::Release} $0 ""
${EndIf}
Pop $1
Pop $0
!macroend

Section Uninstall
!insertmacro UnpinShortcut "$SMPrograms\MyApp.lnk"
Delete "$SMPrograms\MyApp.lnk"
SectionEnd
```