# Can NSIS remove all shortcuts for non-admin current user?

Tags: nsis, shortcut, uninstallation

I have an installer with `RequestExecutionLevel user` (I want to preserve the possibility to launch my installer without admin rights). But I want to know a way of removing all application shortcuts for current user. Does such command exist?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? I see no reason why NSIS cannot do this as long as you are only talking about shortcuts for the specific user and not shortcuts common to all users.

Comment: What should I try? After uninstalling all shortcuts of current user are not deleted automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows stores shortcuts in two places, the users private shortcuts are stored in their profile and shortcuts that are available to all users in a folder accessible (but not necessarily writable) by all users.

Try running something like this

```
Section
SetShellVarContext current ; Used for demonstration purposes, it is the default context
DetailPrint $StartMenu
DetailPrint $SMPrograms
DetailPrint $Desktop
DetailPrint ---
SetShellVarContext all
DetailPrint $StartMenu
DetailPrint $SMPrograms
DetailPrint $Desktop
SectionEnd
```

and you should get something like this

```
C:\Users\Anders\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
C:\Users\Anders\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
C:\Users\Anders\Desktop
---
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
C:\Users\Public\Desktop
```

A uninstaller with `RequestExecutionLevel user` will only be able to delete shortcuts in the users (current) context but that is not a problem if your installer writes them there in the first place.

NSIS does not delete shortcuts automatically, you have to do it manually:

```
Section "Installer"
SetOutPath $InstDir
File "MyApp.exe"
WriteUninstaller "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
CreateDirectory "$SMPrograms\MyApp"
CreateShortcut "$SMPrograms\MyApp\MyApp.lnk"
CreateShortcut "$SMPrograms\MyApp\MyApp (No extensions).lnk" "-NoExt"
SectionEnd

Section "Uninstaller"
Delete "$SMPrograms\MyApp\MyApp.lnk"
Delete "$SMPrograms\MyApp\MyApp (No extensions).lnk"
RMDir "$SMPrograms\MyApp"
Delete "$InstDir\MyApp.exe"
Delete "$InstDir\Uninst.exe"
RMDir "$InstDir"
SectionEnd
```

It is not normal behavior for installers to delete other custom shortcuts created by users. You could theoretically do it by using [`FindFirst`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/FindFirst) and the IShellLink COM interface in `Win\COM.nsh` to enumerate and inspect every shortcut and delete the shortcuts that point to your application.

Pinned shortcuts and jump lists can be deleted with the [WinShell plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/WinShell_plug-in) or by [using the COM interfaces directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42816728/3501).

Comment: `It is not normal behavior for installers to delete other custom shortcuts created by users.` But these shortcuts will be broken after uninstall. Is `FindFirst` really fast command or I shouldn't try this? I mean if this would execute very long (e.g. more than a minute), I won't do this.